# How to saveas the complete web page using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to save as the webpage using VBA whichever is active page.

Comment: [ask] a proper question that meets the requirements of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's not a whole lot to go one here, but if you want to download the entire contents of a web site, you can do it this way.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim retStr As String

    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    With ie
        .Navigate "http://www.wikihow.com/Choose-an-Email-Address"
        .Visible = True
    End With

    Do While ie.readystate <> 4: Wait 5: Loop

    DoEvents

    retStr = ie.document.body.innerText

    '~> Write the above to a text file
    Dim filesize As Integer
    Dim FlName As String

    '~~> Change this to the relevant path
    FlName = "C:\your_path_here\Sample.Txt"

    filesize = FreeFile()

    Open FlName For Output As #filesize

    Print #filesize, retStr
    Close #filesize
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: I just need to save it like we do ctrl+s to save the web pages and save it in the folder.